# Fail to load email interface in SpeakHere project

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, email

I'm working on sending recorded data via email. The project I'm working on is based on the Apple's sample project SpeakHere. The function in my program is that when I tapped stop button, the phone should show email view. This part is written based on apple's email sample code like below:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 

[picker setSubject:@"Recorded Data!"];
// Set up the recipients.
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"yyyy@gmail.com",nil];

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

NSString *path = recorder -> getFilePath();
NSLog(@"%@",path);

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"MyFile"];

// Fill out the email body text.
NSString *emailBody = @"The attachement is the recorded integer data!";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

// Present the mail composition interface.
// [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

[picker release]; // Can safely release the controller now.
}
```

The mail compose view controller delegate method is like:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error
{
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Alert" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] ;


switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        alert.message = @"Email Cancelled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        alert.message = @"Email Saved";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        alert.message = @"Email Sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        alert.message = @"Email Failed";
        break;
    default:
        alert.message = @"Email Not Sent";
        break;
}


// [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[alert show];
}`
```

However, it crashed when I clicked stop button. I feel the reason is that this code is written in SpeakHereController.mm. However, the real view controller is SpeakHereViewController. The code in SpeakHereViewController.h is

```
@class SpeakHereController;
@interface SpeakHereViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet SpeakHereController *controller;
}
@end
```

However, I don't know how to edit the code of email part to set the view controller from self(SpeakHereController) to SpeakHereViewController. Can anyone help me ? Thanks a lot!

Follow Up:

My iPhone can display the mail view if I change the code as follows:

```
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

in delegate file, and then, change

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

However, the new problem is that , the mail view cannot be dismiss if I cancel the mail. It seems that the problem occurs because of the following code:

```
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

The delegate should be the delegate of root view controller, but I don't know how to set the delegate as root view controller's delegate. Can anyone help?

Comment: put crash log. It will let others know where it tripped over

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your respond, I've added the crash log.

Comment: SpeekHereViewController seems to have a NavigationBar. You should do `[[self navigationController] presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];` instead.

Comment: Thanks Larme. It works on displaying the view. However, the phone would not dismiss the view when I cancel the email. I think it is the problem about setting "picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;", the delegate should also be the delegate of navigationcontroller ,right? Do you know how to set it to the delegate of navigationcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need delegates for your MailController i.e.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface SpeakHereViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Make sure to add MessageUI framework

I sometimes find apple tutorials a bit hard to follow. Try googling xcode email tutorials. [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/) is one.

Comment: I've already added these code to SpeakHereViewController. However it gave me same problem. I guess I need a way to set the current view controller to function [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL]; instead of setting it to self.

Comment: dumb question - are you presenting email window as soon as the recoding stops? I honestly cannot see anything wrong with this code

Comment: i think I got ...does the project setting says iOS 5? switch it iOS 6 or iOS 7? Meaning run this in iOS 6/7 simulator